# UseEffect hook with firebase query only render the initial empty array even after the array is not empty anymore

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-native, react-hooks

```
const ID = useSelector((state) => state.userDetail.userID);
const [postItem, setpostItem] = useState([]);

useEffect(() => {
const q = query(
collection(firestore, "latestPost"),
where("userID", "==", ID)
);
onSnapshot(q, (querySnapshot) => {
querySnapshot.forEach((doc) => {
postItem.push({ ...doc.data(), id: doc.id });
});
});
}, 

[]);
```

I wanted to read data from firebase and set my useState with an empty array and even after the data is in the array, the screen still renders an empty array, I need to manually refresh the screen to see the change.

Answer (score 0):

You shouldn’t be pushing directly to `postItem`. You should be using `setPostItem`. Also I think you need to add postItem to the end of useEffect in the square brackets.

So maybe something like

```
useEffect(()=> {
  const q = query(
    collection(firestone, "latestPost"),
    where("userId", "==", ID)
  );

  onSnapshot(q, (querySnapshot) => {
      querySnapShot.forEach((doc) => {
        setPostItem([...postItem, {...doc.data(), id:doc.id}])
    });
  });
}, [postItem]);
```

Basically that means useEffect will run again once you've `setPostItem` and also because `useState` has changed it will refresh the page.

I think that was how it is designed. However someone please correct me if my logic is incorrect!

Comment: Thanks , now I think  i can solve my problem with your help.

Answer (score 0):

The only way that react knows that it needs to render again is if you setState. Mutating the existing array will not cause a rerender. Also, don't forget to return the unsubscribe function so your snapshot listener can be torn down when the component unmounts:

```
useEffect(() => {
  const q = query(
    collection(firestone, "latestPost"),
    where("userId", "==", ID)
  );
  const unsubscribe = onSnapshot(q, (querySnapshot) => {
    const newItems = querySnapshot.docs.map(doc => ({
      ...doc.data(),
      id: doc.id
    });
    setpostItem(newItems);
  });
  return unsubscribe;
}, []);
```

Comment: Thanks , now I think  i can solve my problem with your help.

Answer (score 0):

I'm going to fix the updates don't rendering when passing an array in setState, see the comment line:

```
useEffect(() => {
const q = query(
    collection(firestone, "latestPost"),
    where("userId", "==", ID)
  );
  const unsubscribe = onSnapshot(q, (querySnapshot) => {
    const newItems = querySnapshot.docs.map(doc => ({
      ...doc.data(),
      id: doc.id
    });
    setpostItem([...newItems]); //this now re render the page
  });
  return unsubscribe;
}, []);
```

Comment: While this code block may answer the OP's question, this answer would be much more useful with some **explanation**. Explain what it does, and how it's **different / better** than existing answers.